# PHP SMTP Office 365 - Send attachment

Tags: php, smtp, office365, phpmailer

I am sending a PHPMailer email using Office 365 authentication.

This is working fine. However I am struggling to get the script to send an attachment.

Here is my code

```
require_once('phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxx@xx.com';
$mail->Password = 'XXXXX';
$mail->SetFrom('XXX@XXX.com', 'FromEmail');
$mail->addAddress('XXX@XXX.com', 'ToEmail');
$mail->addAttachment("GeneratedPDFFiles/Invoices/Invoice $last_id.pdf");     
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; $mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

When i remove the attachment line the email sends fine, however with the line there, no email is sent?

The file is present in the directory, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong here.

First of all I can see you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade, preferably using composer.

You're creating an instance like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

That `true` means that PHPMailer will throw exceptions, but you have no try/catch block wrapped around your PHPMailer method calls, so when an exception happens, your code will die. Either add try/catch blocks where appropriate, or remove that `true` param to handle errors via return values instead.

I expect it's dying here:

```
$mail->addAttachment("GeneratedPDFFiles/Invoices/Invoice $last_id.pdf");
```

When you say "The file is present in the directory, so that's not the problem", you're assuming that's true - don't; *check*. This method will throw an exception (unless you removed that `true` param in the constructor) if the file doesn't exist, or if the script doesn't have permission to read it.

You've used a relative path, but your working directory may not be where you think. It's safer to use an absolute path, for example by prepending the location of the current script (which may not be the same as `.`). Whatever the reason is, it's a good idea to check the return value as well:

```
$file = __DIR__ . "/GeneratedPDFFiles/Invoices/Invoice $last_id.pdf";
if (!$mail->addAttachment($file)) {
    die('Could not open file ' . $file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the problem must be with the `$last_id` variable. When I remove this and add a file name, the email sends with an attachment